# Tikz renders deleted parts of graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I defined a graph in tikz via the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) at (2,0) [circle,fill=blue!20] {1};
  \node (n2) at (4,0) [circle,fill=red!20]{2};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2}
  \draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As I deleted the definition of the second node, the code produced still produced the second segment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n1) at (2,0) [circle,fill=blue!20] {1};
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2}
  \draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

No errors were thrown after compilation.

I'm curious to understand how and why this works. Does this stem from my Compiler (currently Overleaf) or is this something Tikz automatically does?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought this was too simple to warrant an MWE. Added one now.

Comment: I don't think your second code is actually producing any output. You are probably getting an error message like `No shape named n2 is known.`, but Overleaf is still showing you the previous (successful) compiled document. Check the errors.

Comment: It threw no errors. This is why I am surprised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any Overleaf settings that would compile the document without an error. The only thing I can think of is that this MWE actually comes from a longer document where `n2` is defined. The second code will definitely not compile as is.

Comment: I am as confused as you are. My hypothesis is that  n2 is cached somewhere by Latex and the last definition recalled without error . But I guess it remains a mystery.

Comment: If you have defined `n2` in a different TikZ picture before PGF/TikZ will use that one but not check whether it has been defined in a different picture. It will act as if it was placed in the current TikZ picture and connect a line seemingly to nowhere.